# Replace in Word from Excel VBA is not working on all computer

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word

This is the code which doesn't throw any error, but did not do the replace on the client computer, but works properly on my computer.
Actually it worked on his asset too, but stopped to replace few days ago.

```
Sub ReplaceInWord()
 Dim appWord As Object
 Dim appDoc As Object
 Dim sFile As String, sFrom As String, sTo As String
 
 sFile = "D:\Docs\Anywordfile.docx"
 sFrom = "#A20#"
 sTo = "Company Name"
 
 Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 Set appDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=sFile)
 
 With appDoc.Content.Find
         .Text = sFrom
         .Replacement.Text = Left(sTo, 255)
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = 1   'wdFindContinue
         .Format = False
         .MatchCase = False
         .MatchWholeWord = False
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
         .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll
 End With
 
 appWord.Visible = True
 
 Set appDoc = Nothing
 Set appWord = Nothing
 End Sub
```

It should be used on many computer so I am afraid to use early binding.
Other macros in the same workbook works well.

I checked his security settings and it matches with my settings so I am stuck.
We used the exact same files.

Update: I got this security notice (Word file doesn't include macro, so it is strange, but maybe related to this issue):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJK9d.png)

Do you have any idea what should I check / try / modify?

I am using Office 2021 Plus

Client using 365 Apps for enterprise

Exact build are the same on both machines, version: 2301

Comment: First I would try it without the Left - only sTo
then I would take the code in the with block, open the file at the other pc, take the withblock change to ActiveDocument, give .text the value also the replacement and step through the code to see if it works in word.

Perhaps a repair of office could help to

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `.find` method does not find any matches (Due to Find Formatting)

To find out if this is your cause of problem you can:

1-Put a break on `Set appDoc = Nothing`
2-Run your code and see if `appDoc.Content.Find.Found` returns `True` in immediate window

If the answer was `False` then try to add `.ClearFormats` in the first line after `With appDoc.Content.Find`

Comment: If you set `.Format = False`, it is not necessary to call `.ClearFormats`

Comment: Thank you. The same code finds the match on my asset and did not find the match on the other asset. Exactly same files, same code.

Comment: @zzzz Have tried the steps that I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I placed "debug.print .Found" after the execute row and it says true, but replace did not happens
.ClearFormats also did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

The Find-Command in VBA is exactly the same as the Find/Replace in Word - you can easily confirm this by letting your code run and check the Replace-Dialog in Word: Parameters (like search and replace term) are the ones that you set by your code.

Same of course it true vice versa: If you execute the Find/Replace-Dialog from Word and then execute your code, the Find will be executed with all parameters that where set before - except if you set them in your code.

Now your code sets *most* of the parameters (eg `MatchCase` or `Wrap`), but not *all*, for example the parameters `MatchPrefix` and `MatchSuffix` are not set. If now your search text `"#A20#"` is in the middle of a word and MatchPrefix is True, it will not find the string.

Basically, when your code doesn't find (and replace) anything, you can check the reason by calling the replace dialog in Word and press "Replace All" - it will tell you that no replace was done. Check carefully all parameters, go back to your code and set them accordingly, eg

```
    .MatchPrefix = False
    .MatchSuffix = False
```

Comment: First: Thank you for your help. 
I have more than 200 codes in reality what we are replacing in the Word file. When I run this code on my computer, the code replaces all of the occurrences. When I send the same files (Word+Excel) to the client and he try to run, the macro opens the word, but none of the occurrences has been replaced. So looks like half of the functions has been blocked, but not all of them.

Comment: Have you executed a manual replace in Word *after* your code run and failed to replace? What happens?

Comment: Manual replace works, but when I place a .found within the with block that gives me False as result.

Comment: My mistake: I placed it before execute, so it looks like did not found, but when I place it after execute, it says found. Found but not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone. I just found the solution.
The word open somehow in a locked mode (so I was not able to edit manually either) and when I saved as the word file it became editable so I save the file before the replace macro...